# Which dependency is required for the jira com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.RemoteIssueLinkBuilder?

Tags: java, maven, jira

I am creating a project to create automatic jira's on some of the actions in my company. For that, I am able to create tasks and sub-tasks but I am unable to add weblinks like GitHub link or any other link to an issue.

For that searched and found that it can be done using RemoteIssueLink and RemoteIssueLinkBuilder.

But, the problem is I am not sure which dependency is required for it. I tried searching but couldn't find the way through which my intellij can figure out the RemoteIssueLink class and its object.

If anyone knows about the dependency or anything else that I am missing please help.
Also is there any better way to post link's to Jira using java code.

p.s. - I am able to create and get jira's so I have other dependencies in my pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and just to help anyone else following is the dependency required.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```